# How can I exit Firebase in this node example?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am running a script and after some issues and some help on here !! I got the script to work only to find out it won't exit after the final loop.

I am using Firebase Admin and I believe the connection keeps open so the script won't close. I tried using process.exit(0), but - it exits before the whole task is complete. In my case I have a For loop that is using an array **id_Arr** for length. The loop should access the strings in the array use them as a partial and do the task required. It all works fine before the final element. Instead of using the final element in the Array the program exits.

Why is that so?

```
const https = require('node:https');

// Firebase
var admin = require("firebase-admin");
var serviceAccount = require("...");

admin.initializeApp({
    ...
});

var db = admin.database();

// Firebase

const delay = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));

arr = new Array();
id_Arr = new Array();
race_arr = new Array();

// Get and Push Lineups Function

const getLiveMatches = async () => {
    for (let m = 0; m <= id_Arr.length - 1; m++) {
        await delay(5000);
        https.get('https://lin-to-API/' + id_Arr[m] + '/API-Key', (res) => {
            console.log('statusCode:', res.statusCode);
            console.log('headers:', res.headers);

            res.setEncoding('utf8');
            let rawData = '';
            res.on('data', (chunk) => {
                rawData += chunk;
            });
            res.on('end', () => {
                try {
                    const parsedDat = JSON.parse(rawData);
                    race_arr.push(parsedDat);
                    console.log(race_arr);
                    console.log(id_Arr);

                    var lines = db.ref("lineups");
                    const linesRef = lines.child(id_Arr[m]);

                    // Writing Data

                    linesRef.set(race_arr[0]);

                } catch (e) {
                    console.error(e.message);
                }
            });
        }).on('error', (e) => {
            console.error(e);
        });

        // Destroy Array
        race_arr.splice(0, race_arr.length);

    }
    process.exit(0);
}

// Get Daily Schedule


https.get('https://path/to/races', (res) => {
    console.log('statusCode:', res.statusCode);
    console.log('headers:', res.headers);

    res.setEncoding('utf8');
    let rawData = '';
    res.on('data', (chunk) => {
        rawData += chunk;
    });
    res.on('end', () => {
        try {
            const parsedData = JSON.parse(rawData);
            arr.push(parsedData.sport_events);
            // console.log(arr);
            var xm = arr[0].filter(function(item) {
                return item.status == 'closed';
            });

            for (i = 0; i <= xm.length - 1; i++) {
                id_Arr.unshift(xm[i].id);
            }

            console.log(id_Arr);
            getLiveMatches();


        } catch (e) {
            console.error(e.message);
        }
    });
}).on('error', (e) => {
    console.error(e);
});
```

I tried starting id_Arr with an filler value - that worked, but that is not the best idea.

I also removed the **-1** from the for()
That worked well, can anyone explain this to me ? Why is this happening ?
Why is the loop exiting right before the last element ?